# Resize uploaded images does not work correctly Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have model

```
upload_path = 'images'
upload_path_to_resize = 'resized'


class Images(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path, blank=True, null=True)
    image_url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    image_resized = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path_to_resize,blank=True)
    width = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    heigth = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)

def clean(self):
    if (self.image == None and self.image_url == None ) or (self.image != None and self.image_url != None ):
        raise ValidationError('Empty or both blanked')

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('image_edit', args=[str(self.id)])

def save(self):
    if self.image_url and not self.image:
        name = str(self.image_url).split('/')[-1]
        img = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
        img.write(urlopen(self.image_url).read())
        img.flush()
        self.image.save(name, File(img))
        self.image_url = None
    super(Images, self).save()

def resize(self):
    if (self.width != None) or (self.heigth != None):
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        output_size = (self.width, self.heigth)
        img.thumbnail(output_size)
        img.save(self.image_resized.path)
        super(Images, self).save()
```

The resize method should take the existing file from the "ImageField" field, resize and load into the "image_resized" field, but for some reason the FormResize form passes the height and width arguments to the model, but nothing happens

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Images

class ImageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Images
        fields = ['image', 'image_url']

class ResizedForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Images
        fields = ['width', 'heigth']
```

What do I need to do to make the resize work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your resize function is not saving the resized output properly.

Try:

```
from django.core.files import File
import os.path
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

def resize(self):
    if self.width and self.heigth:
        img = Image.open(self.image)
        output_size = (self.width, self.heigth)
        img.thumbnail(output_size)
        thumb_name, thumb_extension = os.path.splitext(self.image.name)
        thumb_extension = thumb_extension.lower()
        thumb_filename = thumb_name + '_thumb' + thumb_extension

        if thumb_extension in ['.jpg', '.jpeg']:
            FTYPE = 'JPEG'
        elif thumb_extension == '.gif':
            FTYPE = 'GIF'
        elif thumb_extension == '.png':
            FTYPE = 'PNG'
        else:
            return False    # Unrecognized file type

        # Save thumbnail to in-memory file as StringIO
        temp_thumb = BytesIO()
        img.save(temp_thumb, FTYPE)
        temp_thumb.seek(0)

        self.image_resized.save(thumb_filename, ContentFile(temp_thumb.read()))
        temp_thumb.close()
```

When saving the resized_image you need to pass in the filename and the binary object that will be stored, not just the path.

You will not need the super().save() call if you do this, as you are saving the resized_image field inside the resize function.

I haven't tested this code, would have made it a comment but it was too long.

Comment: In fact if type(img) is File then you can skip the img.save() line and just pass img as the second argument to self.resized_image.save()

Comment: Thanks a lot, one question, to img.save('/tmp/some/temporary/path.png') I need put my upload_path or what? Can u comment last 2 lines

Comment: Sorry, I copied your code without really checking it, I have edited my answer. This time it isn't saving to a temp file, it saves to an in-memory file before saving to the resized_image field.

Comment: Thanks a lot, its works. Last q,how to make it so that I can change not only the width and height, but also separately?

Comment: If the answer is working please mark it as correct for future readers.

I interpret your question as asking how to change only the height or only the width, you can get the original image dimensions using

`from django.core.files.images import get_image_dimensions` and then 

`width, height = get_image_dimensions(self.image.file)`

and then refactor your resize function from there.

Comment: Thanks. Marked ur answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Django-resized extension? it resize your file on upload it does all that work for you and more.

https://github.com/un1t/django-resized

Comment: I need to do it on my own

Comment: In this case try to read the code of django-resized app it will give you some hint ;)

Comment: I understand, but my head is already boiling, I cannot adequately perceive information, I would like a fresh look and advice on how to correct the code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.